# SkipLastField called on an end-group tag. GoogleProtobuf (C# and C++)

Tags: c#, c++, tcp, winsock, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to serialize a message in C++ using Google proto, send it through a TCP socket and finally receive and parse it in a C# client.

I keep getting the following exception on the C# google proto parser:

> SkipLastField called on an end-group tag, indicating that the corresponding start-group was missing

I printed the Serialized Input Stream both before sending and after receiving and it perfectly matches on both ends.

C# Listener/Deserializer

```
 namespace NetStreamHandler
{
    public class Server
    {
        public static void ReceiveData()
        {
            var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            var listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 20511);
            listener.Start();
            listener.BeginAcceptSocket(MessageReceived, listener);
        }

        private static void MessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var server = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
            using (var client = server.EndAcceptTcpClient(result))
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    var cod = new CodedInputStream(stream);
                    var packet = Serialize.Parser.ParseFrom(cod);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Message: {packet.ToString()}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception Caught at: {ex.Message}\n");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

C++ Send/Serialize

```
int bCount;
Serialized::Serialize pLoad;
pLoad.set_command("Test");
pLoad.set_id(10);
pLoad.set_num(3);
pLoad.set_packettype(1);
pLoad.set_ret("Test");

printf("Size after serializing: %d bytes\n", pLoad.ByteSize());
auto size = pLoad.ByteSize();
auto packet = new char[size];
ArrayOutputStream ArrayOut(packet, size);
auto coutput = new CodedOutputStream(&ArrayOut);
coutput->WriteVarint32(pLoad.ByteSize());
pLoad.SerializeToCodedStream(coutput);
auto sConnect = SetupSocket();
if (!sConnect) { printf("Socket failure\n"); goto DONE; }
std::cout << "Buffer:" << byte_2_str(packet, size) << std::endl;


bCount = send(sConnect, packet, size, 0);
if(bCount == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Server: send() failed: error %d: %s\n", WSAGetLastError(), DecodeError(WSAGetLastError()));
    goto DONE;
}
else if (bCount == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
    goto DONE;

}
else {
    printf("Sent bytes %d\n", bCount);
}

DONE:
closesocket(sConnect);
printf("All done..\n");
```

Comment: Have you received all of the message before you start parsing? The server can send 8000 bytes but there is no guarantee in TCP that it will be received in one packet, eg it might be received as two 4000 byte packets. `stream.Read(...)` would read 4000 bytes & return 4000, then called again, 4000, then return 0 on final call to indicate no data remaining to read.

Answer (score 1):

You have allocated only payload size bytes for the buffer used in the ArrayOut that is bound to the CodedOutputStream. But you tried to write slightly more (payload size + size of (Varint32). Guess you need to have buffer large enough to store payload with message length.

I use Poco framework. Here is c++ example code below:

```
void writeDelimitedTo(const google::protobuf::MessageLite& message, Poco::Net::StreamSocket& socket) {
    int totalMsgSize = message.ByteSize()+4; // Variant32 length 1-4
    char *buf = new char [totalMsgSize];
    ArrayOutputStream aos(buf, totalMsgSize);
    CodedOutputStream coded_output(&aos);
    coded_output.WriteVarint32(message.ByteSize());
    message.SerializeToCodedStream(&coded_output);
    socket.sendBytes(buf, coded_output.ByteCount());
    delete buf;
}
```

And of course c# part just using System.Io.Stream as clientStream.  ProtoMsgStructRequest, and ProtoMsgStructResponse are  ProtoBuf messages:

```
using (var pbReader = new Google.Protobuf.CodedInputStream(clientStream, true))
{
    var inRequest = new ProtoMsgStructRequest();
    pbReader.ReadMessage(inRequest);
    {
        var outResponse = new ProtoMsgStructResponse();
        using (var pbWriter = new Google.Protobuf.CodedOutputStream(clientStream, true))
        {
            pbWriter.WriteMessage(outResponse);
        }
    }
}
```